# How to send data in form-data nodejs rest API

Tags: node.js

**Its take input in body row json formate. I using POSTMAN tool for getting response.**

````
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        mobile: req.body.mobile
});```
````

Comment: What are you using in front-end?

Comment: I think you have to add more context, but otherwise, check out this shor blog post
[post](https://flaviocopes.com/express-forms/)